# clients only push to git without pulling

Tags: git

I need to create a log repositories that all clients will push log files into repository
problem that if each client pushing to the git repository - I don't need them to pull or for that matter pull other logs for other clients

meaning creating one drop repositories for logs for whom ever connect to the repository can connect and pull them

I was thinking maybe create to each client a branch and do a job to merge them to the master

is there a way to only push from the clients , not pulling

Comment: What is the question? What is the issue with your proposed solution?

Comment: I'd reconsider using Git for this. Git is a SCM software, not a log aggregation tool.

Comment: Use an FTP server? If you must, you can create orphan branches and merge unrelated histories to combine them into your main branch. But this doesn't sound like a good fit for Git.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a partial clone and create a directory of your own client and add a file under that directory. Than do pull and push cycle as usual. Since it is partial clone, it will never download other directories.

Example:

```
git clone --filter=blob:none --sparse <your-url>
cd your-working-copy
mkdir client-specific-dir
cd client-specific-dir
touch log.txt
git add log.txt
git commit -m 'message'
git pull --rebase
git push
# later after updating log.txt
git add log.txt
git commit -m 'message'
git pull --rebase
git push
```

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/partial_clone.html - like this?

Comment: @Izikon yes. To do this, server should also support partial clone. My example works on Github and should work on Gitlab.